# Why does for loop takes only the last string in this simple code?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++.
I will get to the point.I want to print out even-indexed and odd indexed letters of some strings.

Example :string "Hello"should be printed like "Hlo el".
  but in this code if i choose 2 strings, the code only takes the last one.
I hope you understand me.Sorry for bad English.

```
int main() {
    string S;
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    for (int a=0;a<T;a++){
        cin>>S;
    }
    for (int a=0;a<=S.length();a+=2){
        cout<<S[a];
    }
    for (int c=1;c<=S.length();c+=2){
        cout<<S[c];
    }
}
```

Note: I want to enter all the strings first.That's why I didn't include the other two loops in the first one.

Comment: Move the last 2 `for` loops to inside the first one.

Comment: `cin >> S` overrides S. That's why it's equal to your last input.

Answer (score -1):

You have to store all strings in a container like vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int T;
    std::cin >> T;
    std::vector<std::string> Ss(T);
    for (auto &S : Ss){
        std::cin>>S;
    }
    for (const auto &S : Ss) {
        for (std::size_t a=0;a<=S.length();a+=2){
            std::cout<<S[a];
        }
        for (std::size_t c=1;c<=S.length();c+=2){
            std::cout<<S[c];
        }
    }
}
```